# Javascript function for user need to call

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in javascript. I need to add one function in my web application, in this function in I have added one task. this task depends on a timer, after 35 seconds it will be automatically started. but the thing is if the user doesn't want to wait for 35 seconds then it will be starting before 35 seconds. user clicks on the start button to call function and it will be task start.

if the user waits for 35 seconds then the task will be an automatic start.

This is my function

```js
setTimeout(
  function hello() {
    console.log('Hello User')
  }, 35000);
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Click me to start</button>
```

this code is work but the user clicks on the start button to call function. then after 35 seconds to repeatedly automatically task starts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) like below inside `hello` function. Assign return value from `setTimeout` to any `object`. And you can `cancel a timeout` with `clearTimeout(object)`.

Also define `hello` outside `setTimeout`. As `setTimeout` accepts `callback` function as parameter you can simply use `hello` without `()` as `parameter` like `setTimeout(hello, 5000);`. Or you can define like `setTimeout(function() { hello(); }, 5000)`.

As your comment if you want to call another function after 10 seconds, you can again use `setTimeout(nextTask, 10000, 'This is parameter');`. I have shown how to pass parameter also with `setTimeout`.

If you want `clearTimeout` for next function call also then define global variable to hold return value of `setTimeout(nextTask, 10000, 'This is parameter');` and use `clearTimeout(timeoutNextTask);`. Otherwise no need for it.

Try it below.

```js
function hello() {
  console.log('Hello User');
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeoutNextTask = setTimeout(nextTask, 10000, 'This is parameter');
}

function nextTask(x) {
  clearTimeout(timeoutNextTask);
  console.log(x);
}

var timeoutNextTask;
var timeout = setTimeout(hello, 5000);
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Click me to start</button>
```

Comment: Hello @Karan it's useful for me. it's possible? if the user clicked the start button then after 10 seconds to call another function directly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the function outside the setTimeout. This should work

```js
function hello() {
  console.log('Hello User')
}

setTimeout( function() {
  hello();
}, 5000)
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Click to start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Named function expressions doesn't implicitly create variables of the same name in the current scope. Only function *declarations* do that.

Define a function separately to passing it to `setTimeout`.

```
function hello() {
  console.log('Hello User')
}

setTimeout(hello, 35000);
```